# How to exit a page without reinstalling Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ios, iphone

[image]

It doesn’t allow me to tap on the tabs, so I am stuck on this page. I also don’t want to tap OK as I suspect that it could trigger some malicious JavaScript code and steal my information. I also can’t go to private mode. What should I do?

Update: I tried to turn off data but it seemed like the page loaded anyway. And since I cannot reach the menu, I can’t clear the cache.

Comment: if you double-tap on the home button you should be able to fling (swipe up)  the app off the top of the screen, this will remove it from running and allow you to launch the app fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Tapping OK won't trigger malicious JavaScript code that steals your information. It is safe to tap OK.

Just tap OK and then close the tab.

Comment: Yes it will https://stackoverflow.com/a/252959/5531761 all I need to do is execute that function in a if(confirm()) scope ...

Comment: No, that is incorrect. The confirm() function will not allow the Javascript access to more cookies. There's simply nothing dangerous there.